# Xamarin Shared Project on Rider?

Tags: xamarin, mobile-application, jetbrains-ide, rider, shared-project

Does JetBrains Rider support Xamarin Shared Projects?

I know that Rider supports Xamarin iOS and Android applications, but I want to know if I can use code sharing here the same as what Visual Studio can do. I searched JetBrains website and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Rider should work fine with any type of shared projects. If you know any issue regarding xamarin shared projects support, please tell us here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER#newissue